# On transitive constituents of a permuation group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Assume that the intransitive permutation group G has degree n and minimal degree n−1. If no transitive constituent of G has degree 1, then they all are faithful and all except one are regular.

I solved the first part. Can anybody help for the second part, i.e. proving the regularity of transitive constituents.

Comment: The image of an action on a non-regular orbit would be a Frobenius group. So if there was more than one regular orbit, then you would have two Frobenius actions. But since the permutations may fix at most $1$ point, everything in a complement of the first action would have to be in the kernel of the second, and there are at least $|G|/2$ nontrivial elements in the complements but at most $|G|/2-1$ nontrivial elements in the kernel, so that's a contradiction.